# Lubuntu won't start / takes too long

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, data-recovery

please excuse any errors I'm making especially regarding the terminology. I have absolutely no prior knowledge about ubuntu, linux or IT in general for that matter

However, recently I have found an old laptop and wanted to save some of my old photos on there. Midway through the computer died and displayed a message windows can't be started because windows/system32/config/system (all slashes are backward slashes) is missing.

A friend suggested I try recovering the data with a linux live distribution. After a lot of googling and many tries I have finally managed to create a bootable dvd. (I first tried making a  bootable usb-drive with no success, then I turned to using a dvd bust first used empty iso files). I've tried using this dvd on another old laptop and even though it took ages, it booted into Lubuntu and I was able to access data from there.

When I try to use the dvd on my laptop however, I get the options "Lubuntu", "ubuntu (safe graphics)" and "test memory". When I then choose "ubuntu", the screen goes black and a blinking dash appears on the upper left corner. This also happened with the other laptop, however after about 5 minutes ubuntu started a filesystem check and then I was in the "main menu". This does not happen with my old laptop. It just stays on the black screen with the blinking dash. I've waited up to 15 minutes so far.

Might the laptop be too old (I'm not exactly sure how old it is, but I think it's from around 2005)? Is the laptop too broken? Should I try a different live distribution?

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Toshiba SM30X - 167, model no PSA72E-2L402YGR

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1295447/edit) your question to add the specifications of the system (I could not find it). Although Lubuntu is meant for older computers, it may not work in a computer from 2005. Since you only want to rescue files, I suggest you install a lighter system like Knoppix, or an Older version of Lubuntu (like Lubuntu 12.04). While this version of Lubuntu won't receive security updates, they will certainly work with your computer, and you can use them to retrieve the files.

Comment: Nothing from the official Ubuntu flavors is going to run well on that. Nothing... Use this list and try something even lighter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_Linux_distribution

Comment: Thank You very much! I ended up trying Knoppix but that also did not work. However, in the end I was able to put the hard drive into another old laptop and run the live distribution on there.